# Find and return the list of words that contain letters as SUBSEQUENCE

Tags: python, string, loops, return, substring

*[QuestionHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9qUG.png)*

```
def words_with_letters(words, letters):
  
  return [word for word in words if all(letter in word for letter in letters)]
```

the above code does not work and have tried to figure out why the system does not consider this.
Please click the "QuestionHere" link to understand

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't use pictures like that, make your question standalone and add the content of the question as _text_

Answer (score -1):

```
def words_with_letters(words, letters):
  
  return [word for word in words if letters in word]
```